# How to specify linker dependencies in boost.build Jamroot

Tags: c++, boost, clang, bjam, boost-build

When I try to compile an exec with `b2 toolset=clang` it uses a linking command like :

```
clang++ -L/apps/bzip2/lib -L/apps/zlib/lib -o fixfast/bin/clang-linux-3.3/release/link-static/fixfast-mds_MCAST fixfast/bin/clang-linux-3.3/release/link-static/fixfastDataD.o /apps/boost/root/bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/clang-linux-3.3/release/link-static/libboost_date_time.a ~/infra_install/lib/libfixfast.a ~/infra_install/lib/libCDef.a -lbz2 -lz -lpthread
```

and fails with a long list of undefined references in boost, whereas the following reordered version of it links fine :

```
clang++ -L/apps/bzip2/lib -L/apps/zlib/lib -o fixfast/bin/clang-linux-3.3/release/link-static/fixfast-mds_MCAST fixfast/bin/clang-linux-3.3/release/link-static/fixfastDataD.o ~/infra_install/lib/libfixfast.a ~/infra_install/lib/libCDef.a /apps/boost/root/bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/clang-linux-3.3/release/link-static/libboost_date_time.a  -lbz2 -lz  -lpthread
```

I believe the way I am specifying linking dependency of `libCDef` on `/boost/date_time//boost_date_time` is probably not enough to have the right order during linking.

CDef/Jamroot :

```
project : usage-requirements <include>~/infra_install ;

lib CDef 
  : [ glob *.cpp ] 
  : 
  <library>/boost/date_time//boost_date_time
  <library>/boost/filesystem//boost_filesystem
  <library>/boost/system//boost_system
  <library>/boost/iostreams//boost_iostreams
  <link>static 
  ;

install libCDef
  : CDef
  : <install-type>LIB
    <variant>release:<location>"~/infra_install/lib"
  : release
  ;
```

I need to specify that CDef depends on boost_date_time and hence the linker should order it as such.

Comment: Please clarify your question: I presume your first link command fails, if so what is the link error? Which library is the culprit? And did you read the Boost.Build documentation? Specifically the `linkflags` section.

Comment: @rhalbersma I could try to add boost_date_time to `linkflags` in this exe. But what I really want to specify is that whichever exe links against `libCDef`, which is also a part of my project, needs to add `boost_date_time` to the linker command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/faq/liborder.html
This was contributed by Steven Watanabe.
I tried to help the linker by using `<use>` commands. While that worked for gcc, for clang-linux and intel-linux it did not.

Then Kohei Takashi enlightened me to the solution, which was to amend **clang-linux.jam** and **intel-linux.jam**

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5820

Unfortunately this was conversation was on the boost.build email group, but thanks guys!